# Responder perguntas antigas com resposta aceita é correto?

Tags: debate, respostas, comunidade, resposta-aceita, respostas-erradas

Um [comentário em uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36760/como-fazer-script-c-para-rodar-html/573220?noredirect=1#comment1007244_573220) foi feito fazendo este questionamento.

O foro correto de questionar uma prática no site é sempre no meta. Assim todos podem participar, dar suas opiniões e o conteúdo fica disponível para consultas futuras.

Então há algum problema em responder uma pergunta que foi feita há 8 anos, ou outro período, e que tenha uma resposta aceita? E se não tiver respostas aceita? E se a resposta for aceita for boa?

Comment: Achei muito legal sua atitude de criar a pergunta no meta. Mas eu gostaria de saber a opinião da comunidade… a sua opinião / atitude eu já conheço e eu já vi lá nos comentários. Da maneira que está agindo está parecendo o judge dread. Criando a pergunta (problema)  e a vendendo a solução… enfim eu não perco meu tempo criando perguntas no meta pois tudo aqui já foi debatido e discutido n vezes…. Meus dois centavos eu já dei e já disse que eu fui influenciado positivamente pela atitude de vocês, é assim que vou proceder daqui pra frente…

Comment: Se tudo foi debatido, então aponte onde está o debate. E aí eu terei que falar que deveria ter se orientado por esse debate já existente em vez de ter tido uma atitude de... Judge Dredd. Ah, a ironia... Ou ah, a projeção. Tudo que fizer para melhorar o site será aplaudido (ainda que silenciosamente) e incentivado, mas atitudes de retaliação não.

Comment: @Danizavtz Se discorda, vc pode escrever  uma resposta explicando porque acha que não deveria ser feito. E responder a própria pergunta é algo normal no site, inclusive no Meta. Qualquer um pode apontar um problema e sugerir uma solução, e a comunidade vota para indicar se concorda ou discorda. Não tem nada de Judge Dredd nisso, na verdade o Meta funciona mais na base do convencimento para atingir um consenso. No caso específico, votei positivo na resposta pq concordo. Se eu tiver mais algo a acrescentar, o farei (mas no momento não tenho)

Comment: Eu sei que questão do Meta é mais abrangente que a resposta em especifico. Mas, não entendi porque a pergunta foi fechada depois da resposta.  Isso também impede novas sugestões, como por exemplo, o [native-llvm](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT-LLVM), que suporta o WASM (e [futuramente WASI](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/pull/1850)) sem precisar do Blazor. E possivelmente outras sugestões, caso haja um substituto para o WASM daqui há alguns anos...

Comment: [Acabei de responder uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/573508/137387) com mais de sete anos com resposta aceita e cuja as outras respostas são validas. Foi somar conhecimento ao acervo do site, agora cabe a comunidade decidir se minha contribuição é positiva.

Comment: @Inkeliz a pergunta é muito ruim, se não tivesse uma resposta que orientava para um caminho sem condições eu nem teria respondido. Pede só indicação, sem dar uma informação sequer. De qualquer forma pode comentar lá, sua contribuição ainda será apreciada.

Comment: Fazendo um complemento ao meu comentário anterior,https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8831/responder-perguntas-antigas-com-resposta-aceita-%c3%a9-correto#comment38713_8831, a resposta cujo por mim foi adicionada apresentou uma solução contendo uma abordagem do problema sob uma ótica diferente das outras respostas publicadas não sendo uma mera repetição do conteúdo já explorado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O objetivo do site sempre foi criar um repositório de qualidade de conhecimento sobre programação.

Qualquer pessoa que entenda isso consegue responder intuitivamente qualquer dúvida sobre o que pode ou não pode fazer no site. Claro que algumas coisas são mais nebulosas e pode caber interpretação, mas algumas são bem simples de responder. **A filosofia do site deveria ser a linha mestre para tomar decisões**.

> Para um repositório de qualidade de conhecimento sobre programação importa quando a pergunta foi feita ou quando ela recebeu resposta?

Claro que não, informação útil não importa a data. Se ela é inútil ela pode ser apagada.

De fato, informação que não faz mais sentido não deveria ter no site. Então estritamente falando a resposta aceita poderia ser apagada, porque aquilo não faz sentido mais. Não fazia na época também, mas passou batido.

> Para um repositório de qualidade de conhecimento sobre programação, tendo uma resposta aceita, não deve ter outras respostas?

Pelo contrário, incentiva-se que haja o máximo de respostas possíveis, claro que se deve observar a qualidade das respostas, mas mesmo as ruins são ok de postar, ainda que não desejáveis.

Alguns usuários gostam de achar onde não tem respostas boas em perguntas antigas para dar uma resposta melhor. Assim quem achar essa resposta tenha uma informação melhor.

Como poderia ser correto privilegiar uma resposta ruim?

> Para um repositório de qualidade de conhecimento sobre programação, se a resposta aceita tem qualidade pode postar outras respostas?

Não importa, qualquer complemento, atualização, alternativa, outra visão ou algo postado de outra forma, é benvinda. O que deveria evitar é plágio, copiar outra resposta.

Respostas aceitas não são garantia de qualidade, respostas com vários votos também não, mas pode indicar melhor que a resposta é boa. Respostas mais recentes tendem a ter poucos votos porque quase ninguém participa mais do site, o que faz ainda mais importante votar certo, ressaltar o que é bom e não o que é ruim.

Há um enorme histórico de respostas aceitas serem ruins. Um repositório de qualidade de conhecimento sobre programação é o oposto de ajuda individual, e a resposta aceita é só um indicador de que houve ajuda individual.

> Para um repositório de qualidade de conhecimento sobre programação, uma resposta que atualiza e posta o que é correto, ou pelo menos mais correto na atualizada ou mesmo antes, deveria ser negativada?

Não. Respostas corretas devem ser positivadas, jamais negativadas. O máximo que poderia acontecer é ser neutro. Um negativo em resposta correta é um erro.

> Para um repositório de qualidade de conhecimento sobre programação, uma resposta errada ou desatualizada deveria receber um positivo?

Não. Jamais o erro deveria ser positivado, no máximo poderia ficar neutro. Eu ia negativar a respostas aceita, evitei para não parecer que eu estava querendo privilegiar a minha resposta, mas agora começa ficar inevitável.

## Caso específico

Aquela pergunta era ruim, tanto que eu joguei em chat pra ver se a comunidade queria fechá-la. Talvez ela nunca deveria ter sido respondida. Mas foi. E é melhor ter uma resposta melhor do que uma ruim. Se alguém achá-la terá pelo menos um contraponto que fala de algo mais atual e mais correto (lembrando que a resposta aceita não era boa nem na época).

De fato, se o comentador achou a resposta (a pergunta não foi para o *feed* por estar bastante negativada - não acho que deveria ter tantos negativos, talvez tenha por ter uma resposta aceita ruim, torna a pergunta menos útil) então ela é "achável" e atrai interesse, precisa uma resposta melhor. Lamento que o mesmo tenha preferido positivar a resposta errada e negativar a certa.

Se tinha dúvida se era certo ou não deveria ter votado, deveria ter aberto uma discussão no meta. Se tinha certeza, então precisa rever os conceitos do que é o SOpt. Votação assim, ainda mais por outros indícios, passa uma impressão de retaliação, o que não é correto e não é permitido no SOpt.

Gostar ou não que tenha respostas assim não é algo importante, a filosofia do site indica que é correto e até desejável, quase "obrigatório" que se faça isso, o absurdo seria ver uma resposta errada e deixá-la lá como se fosse certa, demonstraria até falta de profissionalismo, desleixo. É difícil defender que a nova resposta piorou o conteúdo. E é difícil defender que o que melhorou deveria ser errado. Mas estamos aqui para ouvir todos os lados e argumentos.

O comentário lá poderia ser usado para questionar se tem erro na resposta. O negativo indica que tem, mas o comentário não fala nada, talvez porque o foco e critério do voto esteja errado.

Comment: Ressalva importante para quem for responder perguntas velhas: O trecho _"Respostas corretas devem ser positivadas, jamais negativadas. O máximo que poderia acontecer é ser neutro. Um negativo em resposta correta é um erro."_  só vale para respostas que **agreguem algo de fato** no post. Em respostas que só repetem o que já tem nas outras, que é problema conhecido de longa data na rede, o negativo passa a ser adequado, como em qualquer ruído. Em respostas com intervalo bem curto de tempo é comum ter soluções bastante similares. Num intervalo maior, não se justificam respostas de mesmo teor.

Comment: Ah sim, claro... Eu fiz dezenas de respostas ao longo de meses (agora acho que terminei) e deu muito trabalho porque fui revisando milhares de perguntas e só respondi as que eu achei problemas, onde eu pude dar uma resposta certa onde tinha erro nas outras, onde pude dar mais eficiência, ou que fiz algo que funciona e as antigas não funcionam mais, ou ainda complementei com informações novas que as outras respostas não tinham, até mesmo uma visão diferente, nunca foi pra encher linguiça, nunca peguei perguntas ao acaso ou fiz de baciada, atendi ao objetivo do site. Deixei passar algumas.